# In Google Sheets, is there a MATCH or INDEX formula that will show multiple matching cells? [example provided]

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a formula that matches and indexes from a sheet called Events and it going into a sheet called readyishJuly. The problem is that if I have 2 events with the same date, it will only show 1 of them. I'm not sure how to trigger an array search (making up that term cuz it sounds similar to what I'm thinking about). Below a workable sheet made for y'all to pick at. Thanks in advance. I would be more specific if I understood what I was asking for better.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F46br9YQ29guHGZS_VCGGT0T8X6mlbdKjMH-zdygQXE/edit?usp=sharing

[Events being called from Events sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6dwb.png)

[Where I would like it to show up in readyishJuly sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jYy5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(Events!B6:B, Events!J6:J=G10)
```

[image]

Comment: That seems to solve my issue but it created another one. When it filters through Events and doesn't find a match it is returning #N/A

Comment: Actually, I figured it out using the following - 

=IF(ISERROR(FILTER(Events!$B$6:$B, Events!$J$6:$J=I$10)),"",FILTER(Events!$B$6:$B, Events!$J$6:$J=I$10))

Comment: @EddieBonetDiaz you dont need `IF` statement, just: `=IFERROR(FILTER(Events!B6:B, Events!J6:J=G10))`

Comment: I just tried that but it still gives me #REF! for the cells that currently don't have a date to pull from. B6 references C5, but since C5 is blank for some reason `IFERROR` doesn't recognized it as an error. Thoughts?

Comment: @EddieBonetDiaz you can do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKh9K.png